# Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Movie': title, image, id, description

Tags: typescript, dictionary, jsx

Hello Guys I have this problem with typescript:
CardI.tsx :

```
import {
  Card,
  CardHeader,
  CardMedia,
  CardContent,
  Typography,
} from "@mui/material";
interface Movie {
  title: string;
  image: string;
  id: string;
  description: string;
}
const CardI = (props : Movie) => {
  return (
    <Card
      key={props.id}
      sx={{ maxWidth: 345, minWidth: 200, marginTop: "15px" }}
    >
      <CardHeader title={props.title} />
      <CardMedia
        component="img"
        height="194"
        image={props.image}
        alt="Paella dish"
      />
      <CardContent>
        <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
          {props.description}
        </Typography>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
};
export default CardI;
```

then i map the movie list and pass info to Card to display it :
App.tsx :

```
import React from "react";
import AppBar from "./components/AppBar";
import { Box, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import Card from "./components/Card";
import "./App.css";
import { Movies_State } from "./redux/reducers/MoviesReducer";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
interface Movie {
  title: string ;
  image: string ;
  id: string ;
  description: string ;
}
function App() {
  const MoviesList = useSelector<Movies_State, Movies_State["movies_list"]>(
    (state) => state.movies_list
  );
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AppBar />
      <br />
      <br />
      <Box justifyContent={"space-around"} flexWrap={"wrap"} display={"flex"}>
        <React.Fragment>
          {MoviesList.length > 0 &&
            MoviesList.map((el:Movie) => {
              return <Card {...el} />;
            })}
        </React.Fragment>
      </Box>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Then i get this error :

```html
TS2345: Argument of type '(el: Movie) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: object, index: number, array: object[]) => Element'.   Types of parameters 'el' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Movie': title, image, id, description
    24 |         <React.Fragment>
    25 |           {MoviesList.length > 0 &&
  > 26 |             MoviesList.map((el:Movie) => {
       |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    27 |               return <Card {...el} />;
    28 |             })}
    29 |         </React.Fragment>
```

Comment: From what you have shown CardI takes a movie as props, but you are passing it to Card. Didn't you intend to return `<CardI {...el} />` instead of `<Card {...el} />` ?

Comment: Try out `const MoviesList : Movie[] = useSelector.....`

Comment: sorold no there is a default export in CardI

Comment: Yes the problem was deep in my reducers i should have replaced all the declaration of MoviesList by MoviesList:Movie[] and not object[].

Comment: You should export that interface and use it instead of `object[]`